# Exporting assets from non-standard Symfony public resources directory

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

How can you specify an additional (alternate) location for assets:install or assetic:dump to look in, e.g.

```
`php app/console assets:install --symlink`
```

By default this scans and creates symlinks for all bundles with a `Resources/public` directory.

But I would like to use an alternative directory structure that adds 2 extra levels, e.g.

```
/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/Resources/public
/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Lunar/Resources/public
/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Solar/Resources/public
```

Using this structure, assetic:dump and assets:install doesn't find the files. And therefore I can't load them like this:

```
{% stylesheets '@GutensiteTemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/Resources/public/css/site.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

*NOTE: most of my bundles follow the standard format, but this template bundle will contain a directory for every template so the public resource directory is 2 levels deeper. I also need to be able to install assets in client specific directories outside of the symfony root, but that may just need to happen manually. However, I need to be able to link to them.*

Comment: It looks to me like you're braking the Symfony2 structure. What about:
/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Resources/Templates/Admin/public

Comment: Yes, the goal was to organize the templates in one primary folder, instead of spreading out the controllers, views and assets files for each template in so many locations. I've [decided to just make a `Templates` vendor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27746712/3334390) and make each template a bundle, that way they are separated from my regular functionality bundles and more organized. But I'd still like to know the answer to this question, because you should be able to control the alternative install location. And I have custom client files that need to be installed from non-root locations.

Comment: Did you tried `/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Resources/public/Admin` instead of `/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/Resources/public`?

Comment: @user3749178 Yes that does work in this one case, because it's the standard location. But it breaks up the template into too many locations. It also doesn't work for the issue of client specific directories that are outside of the symfony root. I've decided to make a /Templates/ vendor and make each template it's own bundle. That works well, within Symfony's framework. But it doesn't solve this question, especially in regards to client files outside symfony root in their own vhost folders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your bundle in AppKernel.php ?

Alternatively, if you don't have a bundle class in your bundle, you can use this notation in your twig template:

```
{% stylesheets '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/Resources/public/css/site.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: Yes, we do register the bundle in AppKernel.php. However, that doesn't work, and it would be pretty great to be able to specify the alternative file locations, particularly for client files outside the core file structure.