# Override Controller, Views and Resources in your own Symfony Bundles from other Bundles

Tags: symfony, twig

**How can you override your own vendor/bundle controller or view from another bundle?**

Symfony has a default way of overriding **third party** `vendor` bundles by adding files in your own `app` or `src` directory, e.g. `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/index.html.twig` or `src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Blog/index.html.twig`.

1. [Override Any Part of a Symfony Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html)
2. [How to Use Bundle Inheritance to Override Parts of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html)
3. [Overriding Bundle Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates)

But I have my own custom core vendor bundles in the `src` directory (e.g. `src/Gutensite/CmsBundle`) and I need to override controllers, views (twig) and resources (images, css) in template specific bundles that should take precedence whenever they need to alter the default behavior of the platform for a specific design (e.g. `src/Templates/LunarBundle/`).

### Views and Resources

[image: Lunar Dashboard]

So to overwrite the CmsBundle view in my Lunar template, I may put files here:

```
Templates/LunarBundle/Resources/GutensiteCmsBundle/views/dash.html.twig
Templates/LunarBundle/Resources/GutensiteCmsBundle/public/css/dash.css
Templates/LunarBundle/Resources/GutensiteCmsBundle/public/images/icon.png
```

If I make my own `dash.html.twig` template I could reference the files locally, e.g.

```
{% stylesheets '@TemplatesAdminBundle/Resources/GutensiteCmsBundle/public/css/dash.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

But if I only added a custom image or css, the original `Gutensite\CmsBundle\Resources\views\dash.html.twig` template would find the custom css in my `TemplatesLunarBundle` when it was referenced as:

```
{% stylesheets '@GutensiteCmsBundle/Resources/public/css/dash.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

**But Symfony default behavior doesn't allow you to override your own bundles from your own bundles. So how do you do this?**

### Controllers

I need the same overriding capabilities for controllers. One template bundle (e.g. `Templates\LunarBundle` may need to overwrite a lot of different core vendor bundles (e.g. `Gutensite\CmsBundle\Controllers\DashController.php` and `Gutensite\ArticleBundle\Controllers\ArticleController.php`). So [this method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) to reference the "parent" wouldn't work, since that's designed for OneToOne bundle overriding.

Currently the only method I know of is to tell Symfony to find alternative files in the same namespace, e.g. in my primary controller I register the namespace `Gutensite` to alternative locations.

```
$loader = $GLOBALS['loader'];
// path to the user's current template
$loader->add('Gutensite',   $template->getPath().'/src', true);
// path to the user's custom client files
$loader->add('Gutensite',   \Gutensite\PATH_CLIENT.'/src', true);
```

And then I would put my custom controllers in a directory like this in my template:

```
Templates\LunarBundle\src\Gutensite\CmsBundle\Controllers\DashController.php
```

**This works, but I'd like feedback on potential problems or better solutions.**

Comment: I need exactly the same capabilities.. Would be great if you share your approaches if you get any more.. Ty

Comment: will appreciate if you can share the solution

Comment: no solution found yet...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something for you: https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle

> This bundle provides you the possibility to add themes to each bundle. In your bundle directory it will look under Resources/themes/ or fall back to the normal Resources/views if no matching file was found.

Especially see the [configuration for Theme Cascading Order](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle#theme-cascading-order)